# Dealing with heteroscedasticity in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity

I collected crop yield data for many years across multiple locations, which are nested under provinces and some associated weather data. I am interested in making a model and then using new weather data to predict yield across these locations.

Here's a model I fitted

```
library(lme4)


Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: 
log(yield) ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 +  I(x2^2) + x3 + I(x3^2) +  
             x4 + I(x4^2) + x5 + I(x5^2) +  
             x6 + I(x6^2) + x7 + I(x7^2) +  
             x8 + I(x8^2) + x9 + x10 +  
             I(x10^2) + x11 + I(x11^2) + year +  
            (year | province/location)
Data: dat

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
-11495.4 -11261.8   5777.7 -11555.4    17735 

Scaled residuals: 
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4276 -0.5241  0.1373  0.6644  4.7144 

Random effects:
Groups            Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
location:province (Intercept) 0.0028622 0.05350       
                   year        0.0005911 0.02431  0.46 
province          (Intercept) 0.0028255 0.05316       
                   year        0.0003357 0.01832  -0.52
Residual                      0.0296151 0.17209       
Number of obs: 17765, groups:  
location:province, 174; province, 14

Fixed effects:
            Estimate  Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 7.77016483  0.01642658 473.024
x1          0.01490593  0.00286908   5.195
I(x1^2)    -0.00034555  0.00070202  -0.492
x2         -0.00093958  0.00300568  -0.313
I(x2^2)    -0.00008501  0.00056272  -0.151
x3          0.03302874  0.00226069  14.610
I(x3^2)     0.00664297  0.00142503   4.662
x4         -0.04088568  0.00252176 -16.213
I(x4^2)    -0.01398973  0.00139918  -9.998
x5          0.01764166  0.00374300   4.713
I(x5^2)    -0.00298363  0.00135861  -2.196
x6          0.00964780  0.00405505   2.379
I(x6^2)    -0.00359899  0.00123643  -2.911
x7          0.01127387  0.00352026   3.203
I(x7^2)    -0.00175782  0.00052768  -3.331
x8         -0.05147980  0.00392094 -13.129
I(x8^2)     0.00166814  0.00077124   2.163
x9          0.00018234  0.00132609   0.138
x10         0.02124123  0.00385797   5.506
I(x10^2)    0.00174181  0.00087155   1.999
x11        -0.02645305  0.00417074  -6.343
I(x12^2)    0.00045353  0.00092663   0.489
year        0.13482956  0.00617583  21.832

plot(mod)
```

Since the residuals are obs - fit, I understand that as the fitted value increases, the residuals tend to move from positive to negative which means at a higher value of observed `y`, the model underpredicts and vice versa.

I would like some guidance on what are the possible reasons for this systematic lines in the plot and how to best deal with them?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accounting for heteroskedasticity in lme linear mixed model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118391/accounting-for-heteroskedasticity-in-lme-linear-mixed-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the residuals seems to suggest that you have a lower/upper bound in your `yield` outcome variable. I.e., are some of the yields exactly zero? In this case, you may consider fitting a two-part mixed effects model for semi-continuous data. This model is, for example, available in the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. For an example check [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html#two-part-mixed-effects-model-for-semi-continuous-data).

To check the fit of the model in this case, it would be better to use the simulated scaled residuals provided by the [**DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DHARMa) package. For an example that uses **DHARMa** with models fitted by **GLMMadaptive** you can check [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html).